# decltype comparison

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

Is there a way to compare the result of `decltype` in C++11?

In other words, why is this code invalid:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void func(T& t, U& u) {
    if(decltype(t) == decltype(u)) {
        // Some optimised version for this case
    } else {
        // A more general case for differing types
    }
}
```

I know that in some cases this particular problem can be solved by partial template specialisation; my question is about comparison of `decltype`s.

**Edit:** The question came up in the course of trying to provide defaults for free functions  through SFINAE.  Perhaps a better question would have been why this is invalid:

```
template<bool B>
bool SomeFunction() { ... }

template<typename T, typename U>
bool SomeFunctionWrapper(T& t, U& u) {
    SomeFunction<decltype(t) == decltype(u)>();
}
```

I've since found another solution (that doesn't involve templates at all) but at one stage I tried this:

```
// If it exists, the free function is defined as
// bool AFreeFunction();
typedef struct { char } undefined;
template<typename T = void>
undefined AFreeFunction();

template<bool B>
bool AFreeFunctionWrapper_() {
    return false;
}

template<>
bool AFreeFunctionWrapper_<false>() {
    return AFreeFunction();
}

bool AFreeFunctionWrapper() {
    return AFreeFunctionWrapper_<decltype(AFreeFunction()) == decltype(undefined)>();
}
```

I eventually got a variant of this strategy working with GCC 4.6, but then discovered that default template arguments are not allowed for template functions in MSVC, even in the 2012 RC.  So the eventual solution looks like this:

```
class AFreeFunction {
public:
    operator bool() { return false; }
};
```

If the function is defined, it gets called.  If it's not, it is instead interpreted as a constructor for the class, which is then implicitly cast to `bool`.

Comment: Note that the free function form above can't be solved with partial specialisation; it needs to be reformulated as a class template to allow it.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be a class template, it can be a simple set of *overloaded* function templates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You normally solve this problem through tag dispatching. Also, you already have the "declared type" of `t` and `u` - `T&` and `U&`, respectively. To compare types for equality, you can use `std::is_same`. However, overload resolution already solves this problem for you:

```
template<class T>
void f(T& v1, T& v2){ ... } // #1

template<class T, class U>
void f(T& t, U& u){ ... } // #2
```

#1 is more specialized than #2 if both arguments to `f` are of the same type. If you, for whatever reason, insist on solving this through manual type comparision, here's how it would look applying the before mentioned points:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail{
template<class T, class U>
void f(T& t, U& u, std::true_type){ ... } // #1

template<class T, class U>
void f(T& t, U& u, std::false_type){ ... } // #2
} // detail::

template<class T, class U>
void f(T& t, U& u){
  detail::f(t, u, std::is_same<T,U>()); // tag dispatching
}
```

`std::is_same` will derive from `std::true_type` if both types are the same, and from `std::false_type` if not.

Comment: does the compiler always eliminate the created true/false type? I would have specialized a template on a `bool` and passed in the type instead. That way, there is no possibility that a useless type is created.

Comment: I get this, and thought it was probably what the answer would be, but was trying to garner other ideas on it.  The actual context was that I was trying to create a `template<bool B> bool Function() { ... }` and `template<> bool Function<false>() { ... }`, then instantiate it as `bool b = Function<decltype(T) == decltype(U)>();`.  I might add this detail to the question.

Answer (score 6):

Why is it invalid? The result of a `decltype` is, well, a type. So it's saying something like

```
if (int == int)
```

which the language obviously doesn't allow.

You'll need to separate the two parts of the function and put the specialized part inside a function in a specialized class, and forward the call there. It's painful.

Or, you could use `typeid` or run-time type information, if your implementation implements it correctly, although that will defer everything to when the program runs (which allows for fewer optimizations).

Comment: Perhaps I over-simplified the question.  I get that `if(int == int)` is not valid.  It's less clear to me why `some_template<int == int>` is not valid.  Consider the analogy to `some_template<sizeof(int) == sizeof(int)>` - perfectly valid, and `decltype` is supposed to be some sort of natural extension of `sizeof`.

Comment: @Tom: `sizeof` returns a *value*. `decltype` "returns" a *type*. They're different beasts..

Comment: not quite true.  `sizeof` returns a _constant_ value which enables the compiler to resolve the template instantiation at compile time.  My question was why the standards committee didn't allow compile-time comparison of types as they do allow compile-time comparisons of sizes of types.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using SFINAE (`std::enable_if`):

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, U>::value, void>::type func(T& t, U& u) {
    std::cout << "same\n";
}
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, U>::value, void>::type func(T& t, U& u) {
    std::cout << "different\n";
}
```

As Mehrdad says, `decltype(t)` and `decltype(u)` are types (`T &` and `U &` respectively), not values, so cannot be compared at value-expression level but must be compared at meta-expression (template) level.

Comment: I get that that's how it works; just wondering if there's a good reason the standards committee didn't allow comparison of the result of `decltype`.  See the edited question for what I was trying to achieve; actually the comparison was happening in a template argument context, and is fairly close to what you suggest.  I wasn't really aware of `std::enable_if` and hadn't heard of `std::is_same`, though.

Comment: @Tom `decltype` isn't a function, it's an operator, so its "result" doesn't have to behave like a value.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that reasoning.  The result of every other operator behaves like a value, after all.  `sizeof` is a very closely-related operator that returns something that behaves like a value but can be compared to other (constant) values at compile-time in the same way I (wrongly) expected `decltype` to do.

Comment: @Tom correct, `decltype` and `sizeof` operate on expressions, not values, and are evaluated at compile time.  Note that the result of `sizeof` is a compile-time expression, so it can e.g. be used in `constexpr`.  The result of `decltype` can be compared to other types, but using template syntax, not expression syntax.